# Answer Text Mashed Up Against Voting Numbers?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[What is happening here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043412/what-is-the-performance-difference-if-any-between-iffoo-and-iffoo-false) (I am using IE7)

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e81c25584f.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e81c25584f.jpg)

Comment: Can't see anything wrong here, in IE as well.

Comment: You're really good at freehand circles.

Comment: It does the same thing in IE8 when using "[in]compatibility mode".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like IE7 can't figure out the correct width of the table due to the code block being in a numbered list. This "pushes over" the cell in IE7.

IE8 looks fine though.

Since it's minor, and applies to a subset of posts with those characteristics, I'm leaving it alone.